# MySQL Insert query failing

Tags: mysql, insert, not-exists, backand

I'm using `backand.com` to make a query that attempts to create a record in a users table if the email isn't already used:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, firstName, lastName, password)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '{{email}}', 'test', 'person', '{{password}}') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '{{email}}'
) LIMIT 1;
```

It validates, but when I run it with params:

```
email: dave@gmail.com
password: test
```

I get the error:

**An error occurred, please try again or contact the administrator. Error details: Duplicate column name 'test'**

Why is this failing? I don't get it.

Thanks.

Comment: please change '' to `` and try.

Comment: no dice - same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use `'test'` as password because you have `'test'` as firstName already. Since you are not providing column aliases, the field name for constant values bacome the constant itself. Solution: provide explicit aliases for all 4 fields in the subselect:

```
SELECT '{{email}}' as email, 'test' as firstName, 'person' as lastName, '{{password}}' as pwd
```

Comment: Thanks, this corrected the issue.  How would I modify the query to return the new id if successful?

Comment: This is a different question, so pls ask it in its own post, not just as a follow-up comment. But before asking it, I would search SO for an answer. I'm quite sure that this question has already been asked.

Comment: No worries, I added SELECT ROW_COUNT() > 0